# What is my GPG keyID if there is no slash in my gpg list-keys output?

Tags: key, gnupg, gpg-signature

This is the output:

```
$ gpg --list-keys
/home/peng/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
-----------------------------
pub   rsa3072 2021-11-11 [SC] [expires: 2023-11-11]
      A8DD0A5173596CE87F613E42E1D4CD2CE69ED220
uid           [ultimate] tribbloid <pc175@uow.edu.au>
sub   rsa3072 2021-11-11 [E] [expires: 2023-11-11]
```

Which part of it is the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add --keyid-format=long and it will show

Answer (score 1):

i came across this today, trying to figure this out myself as i do not generally mess around with gpg and it's utilities on a day to day basis.  as i generally work with gpg and it's keys once or twice when setting them up then it becomes something i forget about.

all that said, i'm like 99% sure the `KEY-ID` is the last 8 digits of that public key ie. in your case it would be

```
E69ED220
```

there are ways you can list the `key-id` / `user-id` for gpg keys. a couple internet searches later the below link gives decent answer as well.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577307/33002